# Climate change question: not a duplicate I say!

Tags: discussion

My question...

[Is the recent pause in global warming due to cosmic rays?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43334/is-the-recent-pause-in-global-warming-due-to-cosmic-rays)

...was marked as a duplicate of...

[Do the recent CLOUD results have significant implications for global warming?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/do-the-recent-cloud-results-have-significant-implications-for-global-warming) .

But the author of the other question specifically says, "To be clear, the claim I am interested in is this studies' import, not the legitimacy of the study itself" (i.e. how big is the purported effect?)

I am not evaluating that other claim in my question, but my question is directed at the plain meaning of the studies (i.e. "is this true?").

Comment: At first glance this seems to not be a duplicate to me, because your question cites things written in 2007 and 2016 while the other cites things written in 2011, i.e. they might be about some related research, but answers would potentially address very different things. I haven't gone any deeper than that though.

Comment: @KamilDrakari, if you haven't done so already, I would appreciate it if you clicked "reopen" over at the question.  New title.